# How to install distribute, pip, and virtualenv on windows without admin rights

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, distribute

I need to install distribute,pip, and virtualenv for python on a windows machine. This is for work and I do not have admin rights. How do I download and install them?

Comment: First, I have to wonder: If it's for work, can't you ask your admin to install them?  Second, do you really need all of those things?  Depending on what you are ultimately trying to do, you may be able to just use a portable installation of Python itself, such as [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) or [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/).  Also, many Python *packages* are installable without admin rights (even if a standard installation of Python itself requires admin rights).

Comment: Well, I at least need to install virtualenv

Comment: But what virtualenv does is create and manage independent, isolated Python environments. You could do the same thing yourself with portable Python installations.